# How does Label Encoder assigns the same number?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, label-encoding

I have the column in my data frame

```
city 

London
Paris
New York 
.
.
```

I am label encoding the column and it assigns the 0 to London , 1 to Paris and 2 to New York . But when I pass single value for predictions from model I gives city name New York and it assigns the 0 to it . How it shall remains same , I want that if New York values assigns 2 by label encoder in training phase, it should assign 2 again at the predictions .

```
Code
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
labelencoder=LabelEncoder()
df['city']=labelencoder.fit_transform(df['city'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `fit` or `fit_transform` to fit the encoder, then `transform` on the data that you want to encode to get labels (if you do `fit_transform` on that data, it will re-fit the encoder, and if you only pass one value, it will be encoded as 0):

```
df['label'] = labelencoder.fit_transform(df['city'])
# df
#        city  label
# 0    London      0
# 1     Paris      2
# 2  New York      1
```

```
labelencoder.transform(['New York'])
# array([1])
```

Comment: What if New York exists in another column too ! , Will it reassign the value of this column or that column

Comment: @Haseeb You specify which column to use for fitting the data, so it will not be affected by other columns (in our case it will encode values from `city` column since we're doing `df['city']`)